# How to make importJSON leave existing data alone, if calculation not performed?

Tags: google-sheets, import

I'm using the 3rd party `importJSON()` function, and I needed a way to make it calculate only when I explicitly requested it.  [Thanks to this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108580/how-to-slow-down-too-frequent-execution-of-import-functions/108583#108583), I now have a way to do that, but a big problem remains.

Now, any time a calculation is performed (which is On Change), importJSON either calculates if I have it set to do so, or wipes out the existing data that was calculated last time.  This means my data is constantly disappearing on me in the middle of trying to use my spreadsheet.

Is there any way to make `importJSON()` return if not set to calculate, but not erase data in previously-calculated cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, multiple import-statements of whatever kind are a path to frustration. I offer a general solution, not specific to ImportJSON: it is a way to always invoke a specific custom function explicitly, using the menu. The code is below, and here is the explanation.

1. Instead of `ImportJSON`, use `manualImportJSON` functions, with the same parameters.
2. This function won't import anything on its own, it only prints "Imported data below this cell" in the cell.
3. Have `ImportJSON` in the script as it originally was, but it will no longer be called as a custom function. For the sake of completeness I included a demo version of this function here; it only spits out the parameters and a few numbers to show that it works.
4. To actually import data, use "Actually import JSON" item in the custom menu, which is added by the `onOpen` function. It calls the function `actuallyImportJSON`, which finds all `manualImportJSON` functions in the sheet, retrieves parameters from it, and passes them to the real `ImportJSON` function. Then it puts the imported data in the sheet, *below* the cell with `manualImportJSON`, so as not to overwrite it. (Note: the data will mercilessly overwrite anything, unlike the output of custom functions.)

Specifically, `/^=manualImportJSON/i.test(formulas[i][j])` is the part that tests for "manual" function and `eval("ImportJSON" + formulas[i][j].slice(17))` is the part that evaluates the real ImportJSON function. The number 17 is just the length of `=manualImportJSON`, the characters that are being replaced by `ImportJSON`.

Limitations of this approach: (a) the arguments of custom function must be literals, not formulas or cell references; (b) the custom function cannot be a part of formula. See below for an alternative.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.addMenu("Custom", [{name: "Actually import JSON", functionName: "actuallyImportJSON"}]);
}

function ImportJSON(url, query, parseOptions) {
  return [[url, query, parseOptions], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
}

function manualImportJSON(url, query, parseOptions) {
  return "Imported data below this cell";
}

function actuallyImportJSON() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < formulas[0].length; j++) {
      if (/^=manualImportJSON/i.test(formulas[i][j])) {
        var data = eval("ImportJSON" + formulas[i][j].slice(17));
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, j + 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Cell references/formulas as arguments

If the original custom function had such parameters, the approach above will not work since a JavaScript function has no idea what "B2" or such mean. Here is a modified approach.

1. Instead of `=manualimportJSON(url, query, parseOptions)`, type only the string `manualImportJSON` in a cell, and put its parameters in separate cells to the right of it. (So, if B2 has "manualImportJSON", then C2 has the URL, D2 has the query, and E2 has parse options.)
2. Use the modified version of `actuallyImportJSON` below.

This version gets all **values** from the spreadsheet, rather than formulas. If a value matches "manualImportJSON" (case insensitive) than the contents of three cells to the right are passed as parameters to `ImportJSON`; the rest goes as above.

```
function actuallyImportJSON() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
      if (/^manualImportJSON$/i.test(values[i][j])) {
        var data = ImportJSON(values[i][j+1], values[i][j+2], values[i][j+3]);
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, j + 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha... I think I follow, that's pretty clever.  It will take me a bit to get my head around implementation of this in my sheet but I will take a stab at it and post back once I do.  Thanks!

Comment: Sadly I can't get the custom menu to work.  In fact I also just noticed that the custom menu in the real importJSON script, also does not work.  There are no custom menus at all in my sheet... no idea why at the moment.

Comment: Yeah I did, several times.  No dice.  Same is true for the menu that is added during onOpen in importJSON as well.  In fact I never even knew it was supposed to add a menu until I noticed it now, because it never has done so.  Maybe a Sheets issue...?  Dunno.

Comment: OK I got everything going, problem was a conflict with trying to merge your new script file with my existing one.  Left them separate and got it all working.  Problem now I can't figure out.  My sheet does calculations in two columns, B and K.  Column K concatenates part of its API URL from cell J.  This is causing your script to throw `ReferenceError: "J2" is not defined.`  J2 is definitely defined, so I can't make out why this is happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: oh FYI it works fine if I place the value of J2 directly in the formula in K2, rather than concatenate.  I have a feeling your script may be treating the cell formula as a pure literal string, thus getting confused by the reference to another cell.

Comment: True, this approach does not support cell references as arguments.

Comment: OK... that's a shame but I can live with it if I must.  I don't suppose it would be relatively simple to make it support references?  Sadly I think scripting that myself is over my head.

Comment: See the alternative approach at the end of the answer.

Comment: Nice workaround, I think that just makes for more of a mess on my sheet, than simply removing the concatenation and placing the required values directly in the formula (they won't ever actually change anyway).  Still thanks for that, and this definitely gets me what I was after!